# Do I have to save once or multiple times vs. grades of Shaken?

Tags: spycraft

In Spycraft, the rules state that a Will save is made whenever a character takes stress damage and their current total damage exceeds a certain threshold.

I have heard conflicting rulings, however, about whether the save is only made once per threshold, i.e. a save vs. Shaken I at 1xWisdom and a save vs. Shaken II at 2xWisdom, or every time stress damage is taken, i.e. saves vs. Shaken I at 1xWisdom, 1xWisdom + 1, 1xWisdom+2, etc. until stress hits 2xWisdom, at which point you begin making saves vs. Shaken II.

Which of these two scenarios is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second, far more hazardous scenario is correct.

### If the agent's stress threshold is exceeded, the agent makes a Willpower saving throw each time he's dealt stress damage

This is confusing because when initially introduced it sounds like the saving throw is made only upon gaining a new threshold. *Spycraft 2.0* under Stress and Subdual Damage Thresholds says

> Your character’s stress damage thresholds represent his ability to withstand the rigors of combat and other tense situations. Each is equal to your character’s Wisdom score. **As your character’s stress damage *exceeds* each of these thresholds, he grows more mentally and emotionally unstable.** (59)

Emphasis mine, especially on *exceeds*. This is, however, not the case, as made clear by the definition of Stress Damage *much* later in the text:

> **Each time a character suffers 1 or more points of stress damage, if his current stress damage total exceeds a multiple of his Wisdom score** (e.g. 1 × his Wisdom score, 2 × his Wisdom score, etc.), **he must make a Will save**. The highest threshold exceeded by the total stress damage accumulated to date determines this save’s DC.... (339)

Emphasis, again, mine. And, as you might expect of *Spycraft 2.0*, a table follows that  details the necessary saving throws.